# JavaScript how filter nested object's array

Tags: javascript

I've this array.

```js
const items = [
  { text: "Dashboard", roles: ["manager", "staff"] },
  {
    text: "User management",
    roles: ["admin", "manager", "staff"],
    children: [
      {
        text: "Create Suburb",
        roles: ["manager", "admin"]
      },
      {
        text: "View and Update Suburb",
        roles: ["staff"]
      },
      {
        text: "Create shoping mall"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to filter this the role name both in the root objects and children array's objects.

If I pass the `staff` as my parameter, my expected output is this

```js
const items = [
  { text: "Dashboard", roles: ["manager", "staff"] },
  {
    text: "User management",
    roles: ["admin", "manager", "staff"],
    children: [
      {
        text: "View and Update Suburb",
        roles: ["staff"]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

What I did upto now is

```
const data = items.filter(element => {
  return element.roles.includes("staff");
});
```

This basically filter the root objects. But not filter the nested children array's object. How do I achieve this using JS?

Comment: Please [stop adding "thanks" and similar phrases to the end of your questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/332043).

Answer (score 0):

For these king of array manipulations I fine reduce is the better way.

```js
const items = [
  { text: 'Dashboard', roles: ['manager', 'staff'] },
  {
    text: 'User management',
    roles: ['admin', 'manager', 'staff'],
    children: [
      {
        text: 'Create Suburb',
        roles: ['manager', 'admin']
      },
      {
        text: 'View and Update Suburb',
        roles: ['staff']
      },
      {
        text: 'Create shoping mall'
      }
    ]
  }
]

function filterWithRoles(data,role) {
  return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.roles.includes(role)) {
      item.children =
        item.children &&
        item.children.filter(child => child.roles && child.roles.includes(role))

      acc.push(item)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filterWithRoles(items,'staff'), null, 2))
```